# null.jpg being returned for carousel posts via Instagram API

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

It looks like the Instagram API does not support the new Instagram carousel feature. The images results only contain https://instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/null.jpg and not the cover image.

Any ideas how to retrieve these via the API?

Comment: Same problem. Nothing to do but contact IG dev team.

Comment: This has now been fixed in the API.

Comment: @hermanschutte I just checked it out, and it is only slightly better. They're including the FIRST media in the carousel in the media feed, but not the rest of the medias. Better than null.jpg, but not done yet.

Comment: mean you want to get caruosel media or just imgaes??

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:
Since last Monday (April 24) we are receiving posts of type "carousel" containing the property "carousel_media" with all the carousel images.**

**Response example: https://jsonformatter.org/89e2fd**

We have the same problem from yesterday.

We have added a workaround to the code to avoid problems, we will discard this posts until Instagram fixes the problem. If the value of the property 'type' is 'video' we check that the property 'videos' exists, in PHP:

```
if ($item->type === 'video' && !isset($item->videos)) { your code }
```

I think that the only way to get the right content now (until the problem is solved) is to scrap the page (with curl, for example) and get the image from the html.

Comment: May 25th and still the same result although [documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/) says the type for the `carousel` should be `image`. :(

Comment: Hi @JohnnyVietnam, we are using the "/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent" endpoint, are you still having the problem?
I have added an example, in our case the type for the carousels is "carousel".
Maybe the documentation is wrong... (or at least it is confusing)

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround use the iframe embed code to show carousel image, thats what I did in [picodash](https://www.picodash.com), you can click and slide all the images.

```
if(data[i].type == "video" && !data[i].videos){
    html = "<iframe src='"+data[i].link+"embed' width='640' height='680' scrolling='no' frameBorder='0' style='margin-top:-40px'></iframe>";
}
```

(I'm pretty sure instagram knows about the issue and a real fix will be out)

Comment: You misspelled the url in your link