# Is it possible to get the user mentioned media using Instagram API or RSS feeds?

Tags: rss, instagram-api

I want to get the authenticated user's mentioned media using Instagram API.Is that possible to fetch those posts? Besides, as of all of us know that Instagram has released a new feature like multiple image as single post.For these kind of posts we are receiving a gray image as image url and type as video.Can we get all the uploaded image urls or the first image url at least? It looks so bad while showing that grayed picture in our application.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API to get media with user mentions.

For the multiple image, use this as work around for now: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42429285/423089