# Getting "carousel" posts via Instagram API

Tags: java, carousel, instagram, instagram-api

Having trouble with the new Instagram "carousel" feature. When using Instagram API for Java I get only the first image in the carousel and can`t get the rest of them. The type of media feed is "image" in this case.

Does anybody know if there is an appropriate way to work with these "carousel" objects?

Comment: you can find with this key post["carousel_media"] so on this key get foreach loop and take all the media. First you want to check post["type "] = "carousel"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since last Monday (April 24) we are receiving posts of type "carousel" containing the property "carousel_media" with all the carousel images. I really don't know if this is official or not, Instagram never document this things, it's a shame...

Check this question: [null.jpg being returned for carousel posts via Instagram API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42417842/null-jpg-being-returned-for-carousel-posts-via-instagram-api?s=2|2.2402)